# Castle ActiveRecord BelongsTo with NotNull=true not-null Exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm having the a problem when trying to persist a many to one relationship using Castle ActiveRecord and I hope someone has a better idea than me with this, the idea is to save a single object with a list of dependant objects in a single Save().

I have these classes:

```
[ActiveRecord("SomeClass")
public class SomeClass : ActiveRecordValidationBase<SomeClass>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [HasMany(Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan, Inverse = false)]
    public virtual IList<AnotherClass> SomeObjects { get; set; }
}


[ActiveRecord("AnotherClass")
public class AnotherClass : ActiveRecordValidationBase<AnotherClass>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
     [Property(NotNull = true, Unique = true, Length = 70)]
    public string Something { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("SomeId", NotNull = true)]
    public virtual SomeClass Parent { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
var someClass = new SomeClass 
{
    SomeObjects = new List<AnotherClass> 
    {
        new AnotherClass
        { 
           Something = "Hello"
        }
    }
};
someClass.Save();
```

But I get this error:

```
Hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

Is there a way I could do that without setting a reference to the parent to every object before calling save?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to override BeforeSave and/or Save in your class SomeClass

```
public virtual void Save()
{
  using(Transaction t = new Transaction())
  {
     foreach(AnotherClass a in this.SomeObjects??new AnotherClass[]{})
     {
       a.Parent = this;
       a.Save();
     }
     base.Save();
  }
}
```

Greetings

Juy Juka

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid. Is there no other way than setting a reference to the parent?

Comment: Hello Mal, then don't set the Parent, but NHibernate will do that in the DataBase anyway. The "a.Save();" is more important. Greetings Juy Juka

Comment: Yeap, that's what I'm doing, the problem is if you dont set the Parent it throws the not-null property exception (and it shouldn't). If I remove the NotNull=true from AnotherClass' BelongsTo it works. But you could insert AnotherClass' objects without that relation.

Comment: Hello Mal, I know that problem from "the other direction". Often I wounder why my parent-properties are null and then remember that NHibernate only sets them in the database and they stay null in the ram till I load the object from the database. You have to set Parent, because NHibernate won't. Greetings Juy Juka